# EmberJS Complex UI with multiple tabs and data unload

Tags: performance, ember.js

I am new to EmberJS and planning to use it to build a single page application with complex UI design which involves multiple tabs for searching items. For example here is how the navigation would look like:

- Customer (tab)

  - Order 1 (tab)

    - Search 1 (tab)
    - Search 2 (tab)
    - ...
  - Order 2

    - Search 1 (tab)
    - Search 2 (tab)
    - ...

There can be maximum of 4 order tabs, and each order tab can have maximum of 4 search tabs. Each search can return up to 500 records.

My concern is that with all the tabs opened at the same time (4x4 = 16 tabs), it will be a huge amount of data for the browser to handle and may result in slower performance or memory leaks if not handled properly. So my questions are:
1) When switching between the tabs (specially search tab which can have up to 1000 records), how to properly destroy the data for the tabs which are not active? 
2) If i am using a html  to display 1000 records, can Ember empty the contents of the entire table container (from DOM)  at once or do i need to do empty contents in iteration and delete just one row at a time? I think deleting the contents in iteration for thousands of records for the inactive tabs would be time consuming and would result in slow performance.
3) Is there any website already developed using Ember with this type of navigation scheme?

Thank you very much in advance for any guidance you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using separate routes for each tab, then it should work fine.

Whenever you transition to a new route, Ember automatically refreshes the view, removing DOM elements for the previous route and then renders the DOM elements for the new route.

As for the memory, you can do something like this to clear out records:

```
App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     deactivate:function() {
         var items = this.store.all('item');
         items.forEach(function(item) {
              item.dematerializeRecord();
         )};
     };
});
```

`Deactivate` is called whenever a user transitions away from the route.  `All` fetches all records currently in the store without loading more from the server.  Though, I'm not entirely certain what impact this would have on browser memory.

I'm not sure how big of an impact that will have.  One of my apps have several thousand records loaded and the biggest performance hit is actually loading them from the server.  Once loaded transitioning between routes is generally pretty smooth.

Comment: Thank you Nicholoas for your prompt response and sharing the tip on clearing out the records. Will try this option. I really appreciate it.